# Eclipse: maven multiple argument string in exec.args

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to run in Eclipse a command like this:

```
mvn -Pdataflow-runner compile exec:java \
      -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount \
      -Dexec.args="--project=<PROJECT_ID> \
      --stagingLocation=gs://<STORAGE_BUCKET>/staging/ \
      --output=gs://<STORAGE_BUCKET>/output \
      --runner=DataflowRunner"
```

The problem is mainly due to exec.args string.

If I use the Dataflow SDK in Eclipse I can put the string in the arguments tab:

```
--argument1=xxx --argument2=yyy
```

The problem is when I try to use maven with the following Eclipse configuration:

[image: maven]

I have an error:

```
Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: --project=xxx

usage: mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]
```

I have also tried separating the arguments with "," and ";"

Comment: Why not defining the different scenarios you need in you pom file ..and just call `mvn  exec:java@configurationItem`?  See release notes: https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html

Comment: after that, I would need to do it like I described in the Maven's Eclipse configuration. Is there any way of do that?

Comment: i have same problem in Intellij. do you solved this? why this happend?
@IoTuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this problem setting all the arguments in the **Goals** field instead of using exec.args in the parameter's table

This is how it looks like:

[image: eclipse]